# electron with react error bin sh build command not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, electron, yarnpkg

I have an electron/react application which works fine in development mode, but when it comes to building and packaging it gives this error when i run `yarn electron-pack`

```
$ build -mw
/bin/sh: build: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

this happened after i installed some additional packages ( the packaging before that worked fine )
this is my scripts in `package.json` file :

```
"scripts": {
"start": "rescripts start",
"build": "rescripts build",
"test": "rescripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on 
http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
"postinstall": "electron-builder",
"preelectron-pack": "yarn build",
"electron-pack": "build -mw"
},
```

and this is the `devDependencies`

```
"devDependencies": {
"@rescripts/cli": "^0.0.16",
"@rescripts/rescript-env": "^0.0.14",
"concurrently": "^6.2.0",
"electron": "^13.1.8",
"electron-builder": "^22.11.7",
"typescript": "^4.3.5",
"wait-on": "^6.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a temporary solution that i found is removing node modules files and run `npm install`

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```